# Metropolis Hastings on hierarchical bayes update question:

Tags: bayesian, monte-carlo, markov-process, graphical-model, metropolis-hastings

[[I have this somewhat complicated hierarchical bayesian model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VaX0.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VaX0.png)

Here the $y$ on $\theta$ are Poisson, $\theta$ are *deterministically* generated from the $att, def$ (and $home$). Then the last conditionals are all normals, i.e, for example $P(att_{h(g)}|\mu_{att}, \tau_{att}) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_{att}, \tau_{att})$, and similar for the rest.

Finally we have hyper-priors on $home, \mu_{att}, \tau_{att}, \mu_{def}, \tau_{def}$ and these prior distributions are chosen to be *conjugate priors*, so $\mu_{att}, \mu_{def} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \tau_1^{-1})$ for instance, and $\tau_{att},\tau_{def} \sim Gamma(\alpha, \beta)$.

I want to sample $P(\theta, \eta | y)$ using Metropolis-Hastings, but I am a bit confused. ($\eta$ are the hyper parameters, i.e the variables at the top of the picture)

Suppose I use an isotropic $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2I)$ as my proposal distribution.

Then metropolis-hastings samplings essentially works as: sample $x'$ fro $x$ using the proposal distribution. Then we have an *acceptance* probability $A = min(1, p(x')/p(x))$ that decides if we throw away or keep $x'$. This samples $p$.

So how do we use it in this case to sample $p(\theta, \eta | y)$. What is $x$ in this scenario? Seems to me it can't just be $(\theta, \eta)$ as for instance, $\theta$ is a deterministic function of $\eta$ and so if we were to sample $\eta'$ somehow, then it seems that should determine $\theta'$. But then $\eta'$ themselves are dependent on the hyper-parameters $\tau_1, \alpha, \beta$. So do we actually sample $\tau_1, \alpha, \beta$ using the proposal distribution, and use $\alpha', \beta', \tau_1'$ to sample $\eta'$ and then $\theta'$?

I'm confused what the Metropolis-Hasting update is applied *to* in the first place.

Comment: Could you please write the entire hierarchical model with indices on the parameters that need them and avoiding the obscure first sentence about the deterministic part.

Comment: Hi Yllll. It seems that you did not register your account, so you aren't able to edit your own question. This is fixable: you just need to follow the instructions for merging your accounts. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts Once the accounts are merged, you'll be able to edit your own questions without using the review queue.